# Put all regex matches in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have an input box where a user can imput data like this:

528|438
530|438
528|439
532|439
533|438
534|438

Then I have the following RegeX, wich should put all matches in an array:

```
$("#offimportklik").click(function(){




            var teimporterendata = $("#importoffkader").val();
            var regex = /\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/;
            matches = teimporterendata.match(regex)
            alert(matches);

        })
```

But I only get one match every time. How do I put ALL matches in an array?

Comment: You might want to read [this regex reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `/g` modifier to the regex:

```
var regex = /\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/g;
```